# How does delta_time work on python arcade?

Tags: python, timedelta, 2d-games, game-loop, arcade

I’m going through the tutorials on python arcade and would like to know how/why a function works.

There is a function named `on_draw(delta_time)`

I looked around the code for arcade but can’t figure out how the library knows to keep the clock running.  Can someone please help me understand how and why it works?

One example is here: http://arcade.academy/examples/bouncing_rectangle.html#bouncing-rectangle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can’t figure out how the library knows to keep the clock running.

**The library uses a *clock* to call your `on_draw` function periodically, passing it the elapsed time in seconds as argument**

Now since you asked details on *how* is this all wired up, let's have a look:

---

It all starts in your `main()` function. You're calling:

```
    # Tell the computer to call the draw command at the specified interval.
    arcade.schedule(on_draw, 1 / 80)
```

So you're calling `arcade.schedule` *passing* a reference to `on_draw`.

Fine, down the rabbit hole we go!

---

`arcade.schedule` is documented [here](http://arcade.academy/arcade.html#arcade.schedule) as follows:

> ```
> arcade.schedule(function_pointer: Callable, interval: numbers.Number)
> ```
>
> Schedule a function to be automatically called every interval seconds.

...it's a shame they are not a bit more specific about *how* the function is called (i.e. with what parameters, if any) -- we have to look at the source which is, *docstring* omitted:

> ```
> def schedule(function_pointer: Callable, interval: Number):
>     pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(function_pointer, interval)
> ```

That's it! It's basically delegating the job to `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval`, and here again, we don't know what params it passes to our function... *I mean we kind of have an idea, but you asked for a proof, so a proof you will get!*

---

Dig up the [docs for `schedule_interval`](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/clock.html#pyglet.clock.Clock.schedule_interval) *(edited for brevity and clarity -- **bold** text mine)*:

> **`schedule_interval(func, interval, *args, **kwargs)`**
>
> Schedule a function to be called every interval seconds.
>
> The function should have a prototype that includes *dt* as the first argument, which gives the elapsed time, in seconds, since the last **time it was called**. Any additional arguments given to this function are passed on to the callback:
>
> ```
> def callback(dt, *args, **kwargs):
>   pass
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> - *func* (`callable`) – The function to call when the timer lapses.
> - *interval* (`float`) – The number of seconds to wait between each call.

**Here you have it: it says that your function will be called with the elapsed time as first argument.** *(well ok, I had to edit that part in, but I'm sure that's what they meant!)*

---

Now, please don't ask me how `pyglet.clock` works internally ;)

Comment: How does this find its way into the `delta_time` parameter? I checked around the source but couldn’t figure it ou.

Comment: I understand my answer was not exactly what you asked for, I rewrote it. Is it better?

Comment: Awesome, even better than I expected.  Thanks for the enthusiastic assistance!